# Accessing Yahoo Mail and GMail using TOR

Tags: address, login

Can someone give me the TOR web address for logging into Yahoo Mail and Gmail?
Also, how much does opening either of these using TOR and a VPN anonymize your personal info, IP, etc?
Thanks Beforehand...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is just about the one to be literally **yelled out** about. Sadly, there's no ones :( In My humble Opinion every system must have a Tor address for an alternative routing, and - even more - the setup is as simple as every school kid can do. But - to support by fact - the censorship, it is not done. Yes, I'm not blaming or advocating someone, but Facebook an recently a Twitter - **do** have it, but not any more so far. Banning Tor exits *just for being an exit nodes* is a lame excuses for a butt-handed system administrators, but it does happens